# Clear directions on Google Map with VueJS

Tags: javascript, google-maps, vue.js

I have the following code in my app:

```
createCargoRoute: function(cargo_id) {
    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
    var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
    var storehouse = new google.maps.LatLng(53.243757, 50.269379);
    var cargo_orders = this.orders.filter(order => this.cargos[cargo_id]['orders_ids'].includes(order.id));
    var cargo_waypoints = cargo_orders.map(cargo_order => cargo_order['waypoint']);

    directionsDisplay.setMap(this.$refs.olkonmap.$mapObject);

    directionsService.route({
      origin: storehouse,
      destination: storehouse,
      travelMode: 'DRIVING',
      waypoints: cargo_waypoints,
      optimizeWaypoints: true
    }, function(result, status) {
      if(status == 'OK') {
        directionsDisplay.setDirections(result);
      }
    });
  },
```

It works, but when I call it second time to draw another route, the first route doesn't removes from map. I read that I need to call `directionsDisplay.setDirections(null)` to clear directions and it works, for example, if I add `setTimeout(function() { directionsDisplay.setDirections(null); }, 2000);`
to *createCargoRoute* function.

But if I add `directionsDisplay.setDirections(null);` before any actions in *createCargoRoute*, it has no effect at second call. I think, it may be due to new DirectionsRenderer object which instantiates every time I call the function. Any advice would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This is not good idea to create new `DirectionsService` and `DirectionsRenderer` on each call. Move them to `mounted()` and keep instances in component options (instead of putting them to `data`). Maybe it help:

```
export default {
    // will be accessible via this.$options because no reactive data is needed
    directionsService: null, 
    directionsDisplay: null,     
    mounted() {
        this.$options.directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
        this.$options.directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
        this.$options.directionsDisplay.setMap(this.$refs.olkonmap.$mapObject);
    },
    methods: {
        createCargoRoute: function(cargo_id) {

            // clear existing directions
            this.$options.directionsDisplay.set('directions', null);                

            var storehouse = new google.maps.LatLng(53.243757, 50.269379);
            var cargo_orders = this.orders.filter(order => this.cargos[cargo_id]['orders_ids'].includes(order.id));
            var cargo_waypoints = cargo_orders.map(cargo_order => cargo_order['waypoint']);

            this.$options.directionsService.route({
                origin: storehouse,
                destination: storehouse,
                travelMode: 'DRIVING',
                waypoints: cargo_waypoints,
                optimizeWaypoints: true
            }, (result, status) => {
                if(status == 'OK') {
                   this.$options.directionsDisplay.setDirections(result);
                }
            });
        },
    }
}
```